# How to Produce a Bclogo Similar to a Given Tikzpicture and Then Align It Directly Above

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, minipage, tikz-pic, bclogo

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\hoffset 10pt \voffset -55pt
\oddsidemargin 17pt \evensidemargin 18pt \topmargin 35pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8.25in \textwidth 5.75in
\headsep 40pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

{\par \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.89\textwidth}
\begin{bclogo}[
couleur=red!15,         % background color
marge=10,               % margin in pt
epBord=2.5,             % border width
arrondi=0,              % corner radius
ombre=true,             % shadow
blur,                   % blur
couleurBord=red!15,     % border color
logo=,                  % no built-in logo
barre=none, %snake,            % border style
tailleOndu=1.5          % border amplitude (zigzag)
]
{\fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont \textbf{This is a sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence}}
\end{bclogo}
\end{minipage}
\par}

\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
]
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=black!30,text width=0.89\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
{\fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont \textbf{This is a sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence.}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

In  this particular case, the `tikzpicture` has text width = `0.89\textwidth`, with `textwidth` specified in the preamble as 5.75in.

I am embedding the `bclogo` within a `minipage` environment. However, when I specify `\begin{minipage}{0.89\textwidth}`---I get what you see in the picture.

I would like the `bclogo` to be of indentical length as the `tikzpicture` underneath; and, I would  like to have the `bclogo` positioned directly above the `tikzpicture`.  However, when I increase the width of the `minipage` from `0.89\textwidth` to something greater to approximate the width of the `tikzpicture`, the `bclogo`, relatively speaking, seems to be positioned slightly to the left of the `tikzpicture`.

QUESTION: How may I take the specified `textwidth` of the `tikzpicture` (in this case, `0.89\textwidth`, but in general, something else) and create a `bclogo` in the fashion described so that its length equals the length of the `tikzpicture`; and, position the `bclogo` directly above the `tikzpicture`? I am compiling with `pdflatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Using two nodes on the same `tikzpicture` it's easy to place one node on top of the other. The upper node (the `bclogo`, named `logo`) and the bottom node uses `below = of logo`.

You can set the lower node text width (`\setlength{\tikztextwidth}{<lenght>}`) and its inner separation (`\setlength{\tikzmargin}{<lenght>}`). The total width of the element will be `\tikztextwidth+ 2\tikzmargin`

To match the widths, I used a `minipage` on the top node with the same width.

[image: f]

In your code the long text of the contents of the `bclogo` was in the title field. Now it is in the body of the environment.

```
    % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{book}
\hoffset 10pt \voffset -55pt
\oddsidemargin 17pt \evensidemargin 18pt \topmargin 35pt
\headheight 25pt \textheight 8.25in \textwidth 5.75in
\headsep 40pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

%****************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\tikztextwidth}
\newlength{\tikzmargin}
\newlength{\bcepborder}

\setlength{\tikztextwidth}{0.89\textwidth}% set the  text width of both elements <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\tikzmargin}{20pt} % set the interior margin in both elements <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\bcepborder}{3pt} % set bclogo border width (no decimals)  <<<<<<<<<<<<<

\makeatletter
\newcounter{bcmarge}
\newcounter{epborder}
\setcounter{bcmarge}{\strip@pt\tikzmargin}
\setcounter{epborder}{\strip@pt\bcepborder}
\makeatother
%****************************************** 

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    
\begin{center}          
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
            decorate,
            decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
        } %
        ]
        
        \node(logo) {
            \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \tikztextwidth+ 2\tikzmargin+2\bcepborder}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                \begin{bclogo}[
                    epBord=\theepborder,    % border width
                    couleurBord=red!15,     % border color
                    couleur=red!15,         % background color
                    marge=\thebcmarge,      % margin in pt %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    ombre=true,             % shadow
                    blur,                   % blur
                    logo=,                  % no built-in logo
                    barre=none, %snake,     % border style
                    ]
                {} \fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont \bfseries This is a sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence.
                \end{bclogo}
            \end{minipage}};
        \node[
        preaction={fill=black, opacity=.5, transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}
        },
        pencildraw,
        draw,
        fill=black!30,
        text width=\tikztextwidth,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        inner sep=\tikzmargin+\bcepborder,%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        font=\fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont \bfseries,
        align=justify,
        below = of logo] 
        {This is a sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence. This is another sentence.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer; however, what happened to the black background which gives the bclogo a 3-dimensional effect. Also, when I run your code as is, the bclogo  produced is considerably shorter in length than the tikzpicture.

Comment: Also, how did you know to use `\baselinestretch}{1.6}`? Was it calculated or was it by trial and error? The document I am working on can accommodate tikzpictures of various widths. So, as alluded to in the question, it would be most helpful for me to be able to calculate---a priori---the  necessary measurement for the bclogo to accompany the tikzpicture of specified (though not uniform) width. Thanks again.

Comment: @mlchristians Please see the updated answer. All values are now calculated.

Comment: Many thanks Simon Dispa.

Comment: @Simon Dispa Thank you for your feedback! Last update: added `bclogo` border width for a nicer shadow. . +1 for making me learn` bclogo` :)

Comment: Thank you again; and for the last update :)